# Godot 4.2.1 Multiplayer, spawning replicated/clients do not spawn in the correct position

Tags: godot, godot4

Explanation: I have been attempting to make an multiplayer fps game and I am currently trying to make a spawn system, for some reason the replicated/client side of players never follow the position I want, they always go to the world position which is a vector3.Zero, I have been trying everything and I just cant get it to work correctly, and google searching I found one case where someone has the same issue as me but they didn't have any solution.

Network script (is a global script):

```
extends Node

var server : ENetMultiplayerPeer = null
var client : ENetMultiplayerPeer = null
var port : int = 9898
var ip_address : String = "localhost"
var max_clients : int = 20
var unique_identifier : int = -1
var game_manager : Node = null

var players : Dictionary = {}

func _ready():
    setup_network()

func setup_network() -> void:
    multiplayer.peer_connected.connect(peer_connected)
    multiplayer.peer_disconnected.connect(peer_disconnected)
    multiplayer.connected_to_server.connect(connected_to_server)
    multiplayer.connection_failed.connect(connection_failed)

func host_server() -> void:
    server = ENetMultiplayerPeer.new()
    var error = server.create_server(port,max_clients)
    if error != OK:
        print("Failed to create server. Error: " + error)
        return
    server.get_host().compress(ENetConnection.COMPRESS_RANGE_CODER)
    multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = server
    unique_identifier = server.get_unique_id()
    send_player_info("Host",unique_identifier)
    game_manager.create_player(unique_identifier)

func join_server() -> void:
    client = ENetMultiplayerPeer.new()
    client.create_client(ip_address,port)
    client.get_host().compress(ENetConnection.COMPRESS_RANGE_CODER)
    multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = client
    unique_identifier = client.get_unique_id()

func peer_connected(identifier : int) -> void:
    print("player has connected, ID: " + str(identifier))
    if identifier != 1:
        game_manager.create_player(identifier)

func peer_disconnected(identifier : int) -> void:
    print("player has disconnected, ID: " + str(identifier))
    var player = game_manager.get_node_or_null(str(identifier))
    if player:
        player.queue_free()

func connected_to_server() -> void:
    print("Connected to the server")
    send_player_info.rpc_id(1,"None",multiplayer.get_unique_id())

@rpc("any_peer")
func send_player_info(username : String, identifier : int) -> void:
    if not players.has(identifier):
        players[identifier] = {
            "identifier" : identifier,
            "username" : username
        }
    if multiplayer.is_server():
        for index in players:
            send_player_info.rpc(str(players[index]),index)
func connection_failed() -> void:
    print("Connection failed")
```

GameZone script(it simply connects to the functions in the network script and also spawns the player at a specific node position):

```
class_name GameZone extends Node

@export_subgroup("Game Exports")
@export var menu : Control
@export var spawn_points : Node3D
const TestDummyPlayer : PackedScene = preload("res://Game/Objects/TestDummyGame/TestDummyPlayer/TestDummyPlayer.tscn")
var index : int = 0

func _ready():
    Network.game_manager = self

func _on_single_player_pressed():
    Network.host_server()
    menu.hide()

func _on_host_pressed():
    Network.host_server()
    menu.hide()


func _on_join_pressed():
    Network.join_server()
    menu.hide()

func _on_exit_pressed():
    get_tree().quit()


func _on_line_edit_text_changed(ip):
    Network.ip_address = ip


func create_player(identifier : int) -> void:
    if not multiplayer.is_server(): return
    var instance = TestDummyPlayer.instantiate()
    instance.name = str(identifier)
    add_child(instance)
    instance.global_position = spawn_points.global_position
```

The player scene just in case something is wrong with it.

```
extends CharacterBody3D

@export var synchronizer : MultiplayerSynchronizer
@export var camera : Camera3D
@export var horizontal_n : Node3D
@export var vertical_n : Node3D
@export var sensitivity : float = 0.001
var spawn_point : Vector3

var mouse_motion : Vector2 = Vector2.ZERO

const SPEED = 7.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = 4.5

# Get the gravity from the project settings to be synced with RigidBody nodes.
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/3d/default_gravity")

func _ready():
    if not is_multiplayer_authority(): return
    camera.current = true
    Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED

func _enter_tree():
    set_multiplayer_authority(str(name).to_int())
    synchronizer.set_multiplayer_authority(str(name).to_int())

func _unhandled_input(event):
    if not is_multiplayer_authority(): return
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion && Input.mouse_mode == Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED:
        mouse_motion = -event.relative * sensitivity
        rotate_y(mouse_motion.x)
        horizontal_n.rotate_x(mouse_motion.y)
        horizontal_n.rotation.x = clamp(horizontal_n.rotation.x,-PI / 2, PI / 2)

func _physics_process(delta):
    if not is_multiplayer_authority(): return
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_cancel"):
        get_tree().quit()
        
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y -= gravity * delta

    # Handle jump.
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("Jump") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    # As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
    var input_dir = Input.get_vector("Left", "Right", "Forward", "Backward")
    var direction = (global_transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y)).normalized()
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction.x * SPEED
        velocity.z = direction.z * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
        velocity.z = move_toward(velocity.z, 0, SPEED)

    move_and_slide()
```

Pictures:
[image]

[image]